# Rotating & printing squares

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, canvas, mvvm

Got a quick question about an assignment in c#, wpf. The task is to read in an XML file, containing one description for a root panel, and from then on it follows a fixed pattern where each panel has a number of child panels, each of which can have a number of child patterns. Pretty obvious. I can read it in just fine, and traversing the model is no problem.

The thing is: I have to print these panels on a wpf canvas. The relationship between parent and child panels is the following:

- the root panel has X Y coordinates to determine its starting point. Other panels do not
- each panel, including the root, has a width and height (not necessarily the same)
- each panel (except the root panel) has a property 'attachedToSide' which has a value from 0 to 3. The value signifies the side of the parent the child should be placed against.
- When printing a panel against a parent panel, we should always put the '0' side of the panel against the parents' side.

So to demonstrate: look at the draft below. The root panel is printed. The root has 4 children. Taking the panel to the right of the root. That panel would have a property attachedToSide='1' to signify it should be stuck against the 1-side of its parent panel. Now since the rule is that the 0 side is the one that should stick to the parent, we have to flip it 90°.
And the story goes on like that.

[image]

Now, printing itself is no problem. Where I'm kinda struggling is calculating the actual positions of each square. The first children of the parent are easy, but from then on, I have to do some calculations to position them correctly, based on the previous panel, and I don't want to take the route of nested if-statements. There probably exists a really simple algorithm to fix this, but since I'm not home in that field, I'm struggling a bit. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Detail: doing it all purely mvvm too (just for the heck of it), so 0 code in the code-behind. The shapes are an itemcollection with a custom itemspaneltemplate and itemtemplate, I'm doing the rotation by binding the rotation angle to a property in my model.

Comment: Nest each panel in its parent panel and apply the according transform (rotate by angle and translate by width or height).

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far, including your prototype XAML and `Panel` type?

Comment: Will try the methods Nico & user3386109  suggested. When I got it working, I'll throw some code here :) nothing spectacular really, don't get too excited ;) Also, each "panel" is just a border in a grid, it's REALLY basic, but since it's all sitting in an itemcollection anyway, it's easy to make it something more interesting.

Comment: Then just the XML and what you have so far?  The basic problem might be that the parents refer to the children but the children don't refer directly to the parent meaning that straightforward data binding is problematic since the children don't have enough information to update their calculated data.

Comment: That's not where the problem is at all. Please read the starting description. The databinding and drawing the shapes on the canvas was never a problem, that part is already working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model for each panel consists of

```
  X,Y coordinates
  W,H dimensions
  R   rotation value (one of four choices)
  C   a list of up to four children
  A   attached to side
```

The rotation value can be encoded as: an angle in degrees, an angle in radians, or just a number between 0 and 3. I would choose the 0 to 3 encoding, where the number represents the side at the bottom. So the root panel has a rotation value of 0.

You are given a complete set of parameters (ignoring A) for the root panel. For all the other panels, you have parameters W,H,C,A but you're missing X,Y,R. So your task is to compute X,Y,R for each panel to complete the model.

### Computing the rotation value for the child

Consider the following cases which show the four possible children for each orientation of the parent:

[image]

The sequences below the drawings are the child R values, ordered by the child's A value. For example, if the parentR is 0, and the childA is 0, the childR is 2. If parentR is 0 and childA is 1, childR is 1, etc.

First thing to note is that the first number in each sequence is the number at the top of the parent. Second thing to note is that the numbers decrease by 1 (as the childA increases), wrapping to 3 after 0.

So if you take the parent's R value, add 6, and subtract the child's A value, and then apply modulo 4, you get the child's rotation value:

```
childR = (parentR + 6 - childA) % 4;
```

### Computing the Y value for the child

Note that the location of the child depends primarily on the child's rotation value. If the childR is 0, the child is above the parent. If childR is 1, the child is to the right, etc.

So if the childR is odd, the child has the same Y value as the parent. If the childR is 0, then the childY is the parentY adjusted by the child's height. When the childR is 2, then the childY is the parentY adjusted by either the parent width (parentR odd), or the parent's height (parentR even).

Which results in an if-else chain that looks like this:

```
if ( childR % 2 )                // odd values, child left or right
    childY = parentY
else if ( childR == 0 )          // child above
    childY = parentY - childH
else if ( parentR % 2 )          // odd values, adjust by parent width
    childY = parentY + parentW
else                             // even values, adjust by parent height
    childY = parentY + parentH
```

(I'm assuming here that the X,Y coordinate represents the location of the upper-left corner of the panel, and positive Y is down.)

---

The X calculations are similar to the Y calculations.

So you start at the root, compute X,Y,R for the children of the root, and recursively compute those parameters for each child's children.

That completes your model. Displaying the panels on the view is easy enough, since you have X,Y,W,H,R for each panel.

Comment: Would only work for panel that is standing "upright" (so 0 below). For panels that are on their sides for example, you have to adjust. And then you end up in the same switch/if-else mess I actually wanted to avoid.

Comment: @TomVanSchaijk You are correct, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

user3386109's answer shoved me in the right direction, but I got some extra info about the problem that helped me solve this. Take a look at this example:[image: example]

The parent is printed with the 0-side down (this is standard). It has 3 children: right, top, left. Now, the parent is the only panel for which I receive an X, Y coordinate. That (X,Y) is the center of the 0-side. Additionally I get the width and height. For all children onward, I then get the width, height, and the side of the parent it is on. Since a child should always be connected to its parent with its own 0-side, I can calculate the childs bottom side very easily using the mod-wrapping formule user3386109 already showed:
bottom side child = (bottom side parent + 6 - parents attachment side) % 4

That's the easiest part. Now, one complication is that each child can be wider or less wide than the parent, higher or less high than the parent. That could complicate matters in terms of calculating the top left (X,Y) point from where we need to draw. One thing I always know however, is that the center point of the parent side to which the child is attached, should be the same point as the child side center that is touching that parent (see the red lines on the picture, that'll tell you what I mean).

Now I used the following approach: I decided to calculate coordinates for the top left point, assuming I could draw the child "upright", so with the bottom being the 0-side. Then, I would just rotate along that point.

Using an example:

[image]

Notice the parent panel in black. I know from the XML that I need to attach the child panel on side 1 of the parent. Therefor, I calculate the center point of the parents 1 side from its own 0-side center. I know that will be the center of the childs 0-side, since that is where I need to attach them together. I then calculate the childs top left (X,Y) coordinate, which is simple. After that, I can just rotate the child along its center 0-side point. Then we get the following result, where parent and child are connected in the center, and the child is rotated the right way as well.

[image]

In short, it's always the same approach:

- take the center of the 0-side of a parent (which we will store in each panel object)
- relative to that point, calculate where the 0-side center of the child will be
- if we have that point, calculate the childs top left point, so we know from where to draw
- rotate the child along its 0-side center point (we know the rotation degrees from the side that is at the bottom)

Done. One extra complication was that each child received a certain "offset" value. In short, this is a positive or negative value indicating to push the child to a certain direction (still attached to the parent). This problem is easily solved with just adjusting the right coordinate.

Now, to calculate all the points, it's obvious that it all depends from parent rotation, own rotation and so on. When inspecting the variations, I came to the conclusion that a lot of formulas looked suspiciously similar. The total explanation would require a lot of typing, and frankly I can't be bothered. However: here is the code that creates a child rectangle based on a given parent rectangle, child width, height which side of the parent it should be on, and the offset.

```
    private static Rectangle CreateRectangle(string name, float width, float height, int sideOfParent, float offset, Rectangle parent)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle() { Name = name, Width = width, Height = height, Offset = offset };
        // Calculate which side should be at the bottom, depending on the bottom side of the parent, 
        // and which side of the parent the new rectangle should be attached to
        rect.BottomSide = (parent.BottomSide + 6 - sideOfParent) % 4;

        // Calculate the bottom mid point of the rectangle
        // If | bottom side parent - bottom side child | = 2, just take over the mid bottom point of the parent
        if (Math.Abs(parent.BottomSide - rect.BottomSide) == 2) { rect.MidBottom = parent.MidBottom; }
        else
        {
            // Alternative cases
            // Formulas for both bottom side parent = 0 or 2 are very similar per bottom side child variation (only plus/minus changes for Y formulas)
            // Formulas for both bottom side parent = 1 or 3 are vary similar per bottom side child variation (only plus/minus changes for X formulas)
            // Therefor, we create a "mutator" 1 / -1 if needed, to multiply one part of the formula with, so that we either add or subtract
            Point parPoint = parent.MidBottom;
            if (parent.BottomSide % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Parent has 0 or 2 at the bottom
                int mutator = (parent.BottomSide == 0) ? 1 : -1;
                switch (rect.BottomSide % 2 == 0)
                {
                    case true: rect.MidBottom = new Point(parPoint.X, parPoint.Y - (mutator * parent.Height)); break;
                    case false:
                        if (rect.BottomSide == 1) rect.MidBottom = new Point(parPoint.X + (parent.Width / 2), parPoint.Y - (mutator * (parent.Height / 2)));
                        else rect.MidBottom = new Point(parPoint.X - (parent.Width / 2), parPoint.Y - (mutator * (parent.Height / 2)));
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Parent has 1 or 3 at the bottom
                int mutator = (parent.BottomSide == 1) ? 1 : -1;
                switch (rect.BottomSide % 2 == 1)
                {
                    case true: rect.MidBottom = new Point(parPoint.X + (mutator * parent.Height), parPoint.Y); break;
                    case false:
                        if (rect.BottomSide == 0) rect.MidBottom = new Point(parPoint.X + (mutator * (parent.Height / 2)), parPoint.Y - (parent.Width / 2));
                        else rect.MidBottom = new Point(parPoint.X + (mutator * (parent.Height / 2)), parPoint.Y + (parent.Width / 2));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return rect;
    }
```

An example of a real life result of all that:

[image]

As I already mentioned, the actual drawing just happens by putting an ItemCollection on a standard grid, binding to the collection of rectangles and setting an appropriate ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate, standard WPF there.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a recursive function that print all the children of a panel and you pass said panel as parameters so you have an easy access to the position, the transform etc... Something in the lines of :

```
public void PrintSelfAndChildren(Panel parent)
{
    ApplyTransform();
    PrintPanel();
    foreach(var child in parent.children)
    {
        PrintSelfAndChildren(child);
    }
}
```